# Turn Histogram into List of Individuals

Tags: python, numpy

I have two ndarrays, one with bins values and another of bin frequencies that come from a histogram. Is there a clean way to convert these into a list which represents the original values that made up the histograms? Note that my bin values are exact and not a range. For example this function with bins `[1, 2, 20]` with frequencies `[2,1,2]` would output `[1,1,2,20,20]`.

Here is how I currently do this:

```
result = []
z = zip(frequencies, bins)
for frequency, bin in z:
    y = [bin]*frequency
    result.extend(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be easily done with [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
import numpy as np

bins = [1, 2, 20]
freq = [2,1,2]
np.repeat(bins,freq)
array([ 1,  1,  2, 20, 20])
```